# How to find if point is inside a polygon in oracle?

Tags: oracle, geometry, sdo

First time posting here. Forgive any ignorance.

But I need to construct a Oracle query that will determine how many points are inside a Polygon or Grid.

I tried to search for an example on the web, but I couldn't find any.

Any answer or response will be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: The keyword that you're looking for might be ["Querying Spatial Data"](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SPATL/querying-spatial-data.htm#SPATL593). Or maybe it's [this one](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SPATL/simple-example-inserting-indexing-and-querying-spatial-data.htm#SPATL486).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as its too broad and you haven't attempted anything yet. Try searching for the topic again and do some exercise/experiment. Then when you're stuck at something and couldn't find any answer, you post a question in SO and please [follow this guideline](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for future questions. Thank you